# 1.Structuring my GraphCool Schemas. 2.How to have @Relation value different for each User?

Tags: database, schema, graphcool

I'm having difficulty knowing how to write my data/Schema structure and would appreciate any recommendations. If you could solve the question on bottom that would be super helpful!

I am using **GraphCool** and have 4 `Schema`'s:
`User`, `Parameter`, `Industry`, and `Post`.

- `User`'s choose many `Industry`'s from a list. They can change their choices when ever they want.
- `User`'s have multiple `Parameter`'s and `Post`'s, and each `Parameter` and `Post` has one associated Industry.
- Some of the `Parameter`'s and `Post`'s are given to the user by default. The `User` will be able to make their own as well.
- As my app grows, the default `Parameter`'s and `Post`'s will change, and I would like all current customers to see this change (which is why I'm not sure how to hard code it).

In Summary. New `User`'s need to be given these default `Post`'s, `Industry`'s, and `Parameter`s.

This is what I have so far. I was thinking I could "autoload" them by querying for `default === true` and then writing those to any new `User`'s. But then if I update the default list, it wouldn't get added to existing users.

```
type User @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  industries: [Industry!]! @relation(name: "UserIndustries")
  posts: [SocialPost!]! @relation(name: "UserPosts")
  parameters: [Parameter!]! @relation(name: "UserParameters")
  email: String @isUnique
}

type Parameter @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  parameter: String!
  response: String!
  user: User @relation(name: "UserParameters")
  industry: Industry! @relation(name: "ParameterIndustry")
  default: Boolean @defaultValue(value: false)
}

type SocialPost @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  message: String!
  user: User @relation(name: "UserPosts")
  industries: Industry! @relation(name: "SocialPostIndustry")
  default: Boolean! @defaultValue(value: false)
}

type Industry @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  default: Boolean! @defaultValue(value: false)
  industry: String!
  users: [User!]! @relation(name: "UserIndustries")
  posts: [SocialPost!]! @relation(name: "SocialPostIndustry")
  parameters: [Parameter!]! @relation(name: "ParameterIndustry")
}
```

**A key question that would help solve this. If I have a `@relation` between `User` and `Parameter`, and I want every user to have said `Parameter` but I want the `response: value` value of that `Parameter` to be different for each user, how do I do that??**